# How do you get data from a link using axios?

Tags: node.js, json, axios

I have the following link that has json data. How do I call it with axios?

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/graffixnyc/ed50954f42c3e620f7c294cf9fe772e8/raw/925e36aa8e3d60fef4b3a9d8a16bae503fe7dd82/lab2

This is how I am trying to call it:

```
 async function getPeople(){
    const { data } = await axios.get('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/graffixnyc/ed50954f42c3e620f7c294cf9fe772e8/raw/925e36aa8e3d60fef4b3a9d8a16bae503fe7dd82/lab2.json');
    
    return data;    
}
```

But, this doesn't work because it is not actually a json file and I can't find another way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your raw link doesn't need a `.json` in the end.

This should just work:

```js
async function getPeople(){

    // exact raw URL, no need to append an extra .json extension
    const { data } = await axios.get('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/graffixnyc/ed50954f42c3e620f7c294cf9fe772e8/raw/925e36aa8e3d60fef4b3a9d8a16bae503fe7dd82/lab2');
    
    return data;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
import axios from "axios";
async function getPeople(){
 const httpClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: "https://gist.githubusercontent.com",
    timeout: 60000,
  });

  let { data } = await httpClient.get(
    "/graffixnyc/ed50954f42c3e620f7c294cf9fe772e8/raw/925e36aa8e3d60fef4b3a9d8a16bae503fe7dd82/lab2"
  );
return data;
}
```

Comment: I tried this it worked for me for the githubusercontect url.